# How to call another Procedure in CASE WHEN in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, query-string, case-when

I have created many Procedures to extract the data from remote database and stored it in my local database tables. The procedures run successfully when i run it individually. But now i want to create dynamic procedure which will call based on conditions. I have created small procedure for the same but getting an error when i run this procedure as :

```
ORA-06512: 
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
```

I am calling the procedure as `EXT_EXTRACTION(1000161);`
I think the problem is i am not calling the Procedure in `CASE WHEN` properly and don't know how to call it correctly.

Here is my procedure;

```
PROCEDURE "EXT_EXTRACTION"(
   IN_KPI_DEF_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0
) AS 
  ENTITY_CLASS_NAME Number := 0;
  IN_EVENT_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
  Select EVENT_ID 
    INTO IN_EVENT_ID 
    from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION 
   WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = IN_KPI_DEF_ID;
  CASE 
    WHEN IN_EVENT_ID = 10049 
    THEN EXT_10049_ACTIVATE_OPTION;
  END CASE;

  COMMIT; 
END EXT_EXTRACTION;
```

Comment: No, the cause of the error presented is the `select` statement returns nothing for `KPI_DEF_ID = 1000161`.

Comment: Why do you believe that the `CASE` statement is the problem?  The error you posted appears to indicate that your `SELECT` statement returns 0 rows.  Are you sure the query returns exactly 1 row?  It would help to post the full error stack including things like line numbers to identify which statement is failing.

Comment: As i said if i run this procedure individually EXT_10049_ACTIVATE_OPTION then it runs successfully and inserted data in my tables. It should always return data

Comment: As Nicholas Krasnow pointed out: The problem ist not `EXT_10049_ACTIVATE_OPTION` but `Select EVENT_ID INTO IN_EVENT_ID from RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION  WHERE KPI_DEF_ID = IN_KPI_DEF_ID;`not returning excat one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to surround select in your procedure with **exception when no_data_found** and look at result. May be this proc work from another user,which have no priveleges to select, or selected object is a view? May be you should create procedure like *authid current_user*?